# How to get text box value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to get the value from an HTML text box but value is not coming after white space

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="txtJob" value="software engineer">
```

I only get: "software" from the above. I am using a script like this:

```
var jobValue = document.getElementById('txtJob').value
```

How do I get the full value: "software engineer"?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

+1 Gumbo: ‘id’ is the easiest way to access page elements. IE (pre version 8) will return things with a matching ‘name’ if it can't find anything with the given ID, but this is a bug.

> i am getting only "software".

id-vs-name won't affect this; I suspect what's happened is that (contrary to the example code) you've forgotten to quote your ‘value’ attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="txtJob" value=software engineer>
```

Answer (score 81):

Your element does not have an ID but just a name. So you could either use `getElementsByName()` method to get a list of all elements with this name:

```
var jobValue = document.getElementsByName('txtJob')[0].value  // first element in DOM  (index 0) with name="txtJob"
```

Or you assign an ID to the element:

```
<input type="text" name="txtJob" id="txtJob" value="software engineer">
```

Answer (score 14):

```
var word = document.getElementById("word").value;//by id
or
var word = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;//by index
//word = a word from form input
var kodlandi = escape(word);//apply url encoding

alert(escape(word));
or
alert(kodlandi);
```

the problem you are not using encoding for input values from form 
so
not browser adds ones to ...

ontop has some problems as unicode encoding/decoding operations
so
use this function encoding strings/arrays

```
function urlencode( str ) 
{
// http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net3.    
// +   original by: Philip Peterson4.    
// +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)5.    
// *     example 1: urlencode('Kevin van Zonneveld!');
// *     returns 1: 'Kevin+van+Zonneveld%21'7. 
   var ret = str; 
   ret = ret.toString();
   ret = encodeURIComponent(ret);
   ret = ret.replace(/%20/g, '+');
   return ret;
}


ex.
var word = "some word";
word = urlencode(word);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<label>Enter your Name here: </label><br>
<input type= text id="namehere" onchange="displayname()"><br>


<script>
function displayname() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("namehere").value;
}

</script>


<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the `id` attribute of the `input` to `txtJob`. Your browser is acting quirky when you call `getElementById`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ASP.NET, the server-side code tags in these examples below will provide the exact control ID, even if you are using Master pages.

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("<%=MyControlName.ClientID%>").value;
```

JQuery:

```
$("#<%= MyControlName.ClientID %>").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is in a form then it would be:

```
<form name="jojo">
<input name="jobtitle">
</form>
```

Then you would say in javascript:

```
var val= document.jojo.jobtitle.value

document.formname.elementname
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided when you want the text box value. Simple one:

```
<input type="text" value="software engineer" id="textbox">

var result = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way

```
document.getElemmentByName("txtJob").getAttribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any user control and want to get any text box values then you can use the below code:

```
var result = document.getElementById('LE_OtherCostsDetails_txtHomeOwnerInsurance').value;
```

Here, `LE_OtherCostsDetails`, is the name of the user control and `txtHomeOwnerInsurance` is the id of the text box.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you made a **Tiny mistake!**
This is the JS code I use:

```
var jobName = document.getElementById("txtJob").value;
```

You should not use name="". instead use id="".

Answer (score 0):

**You Need to change your code as below:-**

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form align="center" method=post>
    <input id="mainText" type="text" align="center"placeholder="Search">

    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" style="position: absolute; left: 450px"/>
</form>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    $a= document.getElementById("mainText").value;
    alert($a);
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you used space between software engineer html/php will not support space between value under textbox, you have to use this code
**`<input type="text" name="txtJob" value=software_engineer>`**
It will work

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jobValue=document.FormName.txtJob.value;
```

Try that code above.

jobValue : variable name.
FormName : Name of the form in html.
txtJob : Textbox name

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple using jquery:

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" name="txtJob" value="software engineer">
```

JS:

```
  var jobValue = $('#txtJob').val(); //Get the text field value
  $('#txtJob').val(jobValue);        //Set the text field value
```

Answer (score 0):

Set id for the textbox. ie,

```
<input type="text" name="txtJob" value="software engineer" id="txtJob">
```

In javascript

```
var jobValue = document.getElementById('txtJob').value
```

In Jquery

```
 var jobValue =  $("#txtJob").val();
```