# How to make text from an input box readable from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a html JAVASCRIPT turtle website, how would I be able to make text from a text input box a variable and accessible from javascript? And I want it so when I change the text inside the text box that when I click OK it send the new text and not the old one.

```
<input type="text" value="Put a number here"/>
```

Comment: Show some code and perhaps read a tutorial for beginners?

Comment: @mplungjan I have searched online, I will put some code up in a sec.

Comment: lol you forgot to add "I have not attempted any code, but i was hoping SO would do all the work". Go to a javascript tutorial my friend, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text box value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763745/how-to-get-text-box-value-in-javascript) - please pay attention to the suggestions given by SO when you ask. You must have ignored them all

Comment: Sorry, none of them seemed to work. and also it's being accessed from a different file, that also is creating bugs, I have looked in the console of Google Chrome but that didn't help....

Comment: What does "accessed from a different file" mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="theTextBox"/>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Ok" onclick="theButtonClick()"/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function theButtonClick()
{
    var theVariable = document.getElementById("theTextBox").value;
    alert(theVariable);
}
```

Try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/65JgK/).

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text of an input box with Javascript :

`document.getElementById('textbox_id').value`

Your input box ID should match the ID in the "getElementById()" function in your Javascript code.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value).

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, for example : `<input name="somename" id="textbox_id" type="text">`. This is because your Javascript code needs a way to uniquely identify your text box, and you should give it an ID and use that same ID in your Javascript code. Yeah, of course you can replace "textbox_id" by anything you like as long as it's the same in the input field and in the Javascript.

Comment: @mplungjan I edited my answer, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Yes, that was much better.