# How to generate a custom url using text fields in php

Tags: url, text

So here is what I am trying to do,
Lets say there is my url

```
 http://myurl.com/watch?v=**XYZ**&caption=**ABC**&link=**http://google.com**
```

I want the text in bold as input from user e.g.:

```
    **v**= textfield1
    **caption**= textfield2
    **link**= textfield3
```

SUBMIT button

After clicking submit a text should be generated "click here" which will should open generated url in new window.

```
 http://myurl.com/watch?v=**XYZ**&caption=**ABC**&link=**http://google.com**
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use JavaScript.

You can take your values from textfield on submit (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763745/how-to-get-text-box-value-in-javascript)) and create your url.
After you car redirect to your page using [window.location](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ι created a page that makes that you want.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function takevalues()
{
var value1 = document.getElementById('textfield1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
var value3 = document.getElementById('textfield3').value;

window.location = "http://myurl.com?value1="+value1+"&value2="+value2+"&value3="+value3;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform" action="javascript:takevalues()" method="POST">
        <div align="center">
        <br><br>
        <input type="text" size="25" id ="textfield1"> <br>
        <input type="text" size="25" id ="textfield2"> <br>
        <input type="text" size="25" id ="textfield3"> <br>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" size="value" id ="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```