# get the value of textbox and text cell using javascript in table

Tags: javascript, php

I have a HTML table generated with `javascript`. Each row consist of 3 cells, which are 
`{id, textbox, button }`. When the user inserts some value to the textbox and presses the button I should add `{ id, value_of_textbox }` to the database through `php`. The problem is I do not know how to get value of id and textbox. How it should be done? Thank you.

```
<table id="numtable">
<tr>
    <td>ItemID</td>
    <td>Bid €</td>
    <td>BID!</td>  
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">

var table = document.getElementById("numtable")

for (var i=0; i<value; i++){

    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= i; 
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="bidval">';
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Bid">';
}
</script>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to add your HTML/code to your question before we can really help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get text box value in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763745/how-to-get-text-box-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Is your question about how to get the value of a textbox, or how to find the corresponding textbox when the user presses the button? Please show what you've tried so far, and explain the problem you're having. Are you willing to use jQuery, it can make this kind of thing much easier.

Comment: @Dan No, it is not a dublicate. In my case there is a table, and in each row there are a textbox and a button, depending on the button pressed I should get the value of the textbox in the same row.

Comment: @Barmar, yes I can use jQuery

Comment: onclick get the bottom, find the parent row, find the input...

Comment: If you can provide your existing code for the table, it would be easier to assist you.

Comment: put some unique id to your text box and get its value using js `document.getElementById('txtboxid').value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery answer (a comment says it's OK):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var input = row.find(".textbox").val();
    var id = row.find(".id").text();
    $.post("addToDB.php", {
        id: id,
        name: input
    });
});
```

I'm making assumptions about class names for the table elements and the names of the PHP parameters, you can change these to match your application.