# Convert a string into JSON key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file that has:
`{ "a": "letter a", "b": "letter b", "c": "letter c" }`

When the user type in the textbox "b", how do I convert the string from the textbox into a key to access the "b" key in the JSON in JS?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763745/how-to-get-text-box-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution for a given problem:

App Structure:

[image]

`app.js` file

```js
const textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
const valueBox = document.getElementById("valuebox");
let data;
async function main() {
  await fetch("/data.json").then(async (v) => {
    data = await v.json();
  });
  console.log(data);
}
textBox.addEventListener("change", () => {
  let k = textBox.value;
  valueBox.innerHTML = data[k];
});
main();
```

`index.html` file

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <input id="textbox" />
        <div id="valuebox"></div>
      </body>
      <script src="./app.js"></script>
    </html>
```

`data.json` file

```json
{ "a": "letter a", "b": "letter b", "c": "letter c" }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about accessing the value from the user first and then accessing the value from object.

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var obj = { "a": "letter a", "b": "letter b", "c": "letter c" };
  var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input").value;
  if(userInput){
  console.log(obj[userInput] ?? "not found");
  }
}
```

```html
Enter value: <input type="text" id ="user-input" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the square bracket notation to access the value of a specific key in a JSON object in JavaScript:

```
var value = jsonObject['userInput'];
```

For example:

```
const jsonObject = JSON.parse('{ "a": "letter a", "b": "letter b", "c": "letter c" }');    

var userInput = document.getElementById("textbox").value; // userInput = 'b'

var value = jsonObject[userInput];

console.log(value); // 'letter b'
```